# The While loop is not terminating even i tried decrementing t

Tags: c++, if-statement, gcc, while-loop, conditional-statements

The Problem of the Solution is that first line will contain total no. of Input and the next line will take three integer and then we have to calculate the result based on the input.So the Problem with my Solution is that the While Loop is Not Terminating.

I have Checked the code several times and thinks that this is happening because of the conditional statement and because of if-else the --t statement is not getting executed.So,what modifications should i do to make the program terminate after t input.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int t{0};
cin>>t;
while(t)
{
    double h{0},c{0},t(0);
    cin>>h>>c>>t;
    if(h>50 and c<0.7 and t>5600)
        cout<<"10\n";
    else if(h>50 and c<0.7)
        cout<<"9\n";
    else if(c<0.7 and t>5600)
        cout<<"8\n";
    else if(h>50 and t>5600)
        cout<<"7\n";
    else if(h>50 or c<0.7 or t>5600)
        cout<<"6\n";
    else
        cout<<"5\n";
    --t;
}
return 0;
}
```

I expect the Program to terminate after t input but it is not happening.

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but you should add some input validation. After you fix the problem think about what happens if the user inputs a negative value (which is non-zero and therefore "true").

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  It was a question on codechef and first line will take the total number of test cases. So,it can't be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside the loop you have

```
int t{0};
```

And inside the loop you have

```
double h{0},c{0},t(0);
```

You have two different and distinctive variables `t` that shadows each other. And inside the loop when you do `--t` you decrement the variable inside the loop, not the one you use for the looping condition.

You solve this by using descriptive names for your variables, instead of short one-letter names.

Comment: This is true, but another immediate problem is that each loop iteration has a `cin>>h>>c>>t;`. So if `t>0` then just providing input for `t` is not enough for the program to finish. It will block immediately after inputting `t`.